# combo box change event not firing via Inserted jquery script into c# web browser control

Tags: c#, jquery, combobox, webbrowser-control

I have a web browser control in a C# app that upon page completed it inserts a script into the document.

The script is to change a combo box value for automation.

The thing is when the script is executed the normal behavour of the original site is not working. It is meant to load some results via AJAX.

Though if I click and change the combo box using the mouse it does work.

The script is like this

```
$("#orderBySelect").val('prfs');  $("#orderBySelect").click();
```

Though I have tried the change event also as well as a combination of other events including the click event on the selected option.

Any idea why this would be?

Answer (score 1):

If "orderBySelect" is an ASP.NET UserControl (i.e. it has `runat="server"`), ASP.NET will silently modify that ID (by prefixing a string to it) when it flushes the HTML to your browser.

Generally I work around that by using this instead:

```
$('[id$="orderBySelect"]')
```

which basically says "the element with an `ID` that ends with "orderBySelect".

Comment: it's not. If I put an alert call in the click method it gets called. Also I can see the value of the select box change. It just doesn't load the search results like it should

Comment: then that just means that your `.click()` above works, and we'll need to see some more code to get this problem rolling.